# Cannot resolve setText method

Tags: android

This is the program.The last line it shows error like it cannot resolve `setText` and `toString`.

```
 public void onButtonClick(View v){}
 EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
 EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
 int sum = num1 + num2;
 t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Comment: All of the lines after the `public void...` line are outside of any method, because you closed that method's braces too early. Move the `}` at the end of the first line to after the rest of the lines you have there.

Comment: i would suggest you to take basic java and OOPS classes before jumping in to app development.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
   public void onButtonClick(View v){
        EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works change the data type

```
public void onButtonClick(View v){
        EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        Integer sum = num1 + num2;
        t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }
```